# Fehlermeldung: unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: php, compiler-errors, php-7.4

I got this error, I tried to solve it but unfortunately it didn't work out.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ udemy \ test \ lib \ User.php on line 6

index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<?php include "elements/topNavBar.php"; ?>
<header>

</header>

<body>
<main>
    <div>
        <h1> Homepage </h1>
        <?php include "lib/User.php";  ?>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Part of the code of `User` class:

```
<?php


class User
{
   /*line 6 the error*/ private string $firstName;
    private string $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $rePassword;

    /**
     * @param string $firstName
     */
    public function setName(string $newName)
    {
        if (($this->checkIfThereNumber($newName) === 0) && ($this->checkIfThereSpecialCharacters($newName) === 0)) {

            if ($this->checkLengthOfName($newName) == false) {

                if ($this->checkOccurrenceOfLetter($newName) == true) {

                    $this->firstName = $newName;
                    echo "your {$newName} was created successful";
                } else {
                    die();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<script> alert('the length of your first name " . $newName . "  is not allowed. It should be  3 or more but not more than 10 ')</script>";
                die();
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script> alert('your marke name  " . $newName . " contain not acceptable items numbers and other special characters are not allowed   ')</script>";
            die();
        }
    }
```

I think the code is right.

PHP Version: 7.4

Comment: Make sure php is really __7.4__.